# Error occuring related to build path in eclipse for Spring MVC application

Tags: eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc

I am building MVC CRUD application. In JSP file I got this error

```
The tag handler class for "fmt:message"
     (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.fmt.MessageTag)
         was not found on the Java Build Path
```

Here is my JSP file at the line "fmt:message"

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
  <title><fmt:message key="title"/></title>
  <style>
    .error { color: blue; }
  </style>  
</head>

<body>
<h1><fmt:message key="addprod.heading"/></h1>
<form:form method="post" commandName="addprod">
  <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
      <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20%">Add a new Product: (Please enter ID for the new product) </td>
        <td width="20%">
          <form:input path="productID"/>
        </td>

        <td width="60%">
          <form:errors path="productID" cssClass="error"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20%">Add a new Product: (Please enter name for the new product) </td>
        <td width="20%">
          <form:input path="productname"/>
        </td>

        <td width="60%">
          <form:errors path="productname" cssClass="error"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td align="right" width="20%">Add Price: (Specify price in number) </td>
        <td width="20%">
          <form:input path="productprice"/>
        </td>

        <td width="60%">
          <form:errors path="productprice" cssClass="error"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" align="center" value="Add">
</form:form>
<a href="<c:url value="hello.htm"/>">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly guide me how to solve it. I added all the jars related, But could not understand the error exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential problems.

1. Regarding the specific error you're seeing, you need to ensure
   the appropriate tag library is on your build path. In Eclipse,
   right-click your project and select "Properties". In the dialog that
   pops up, select "Java Build Path". The window should display tabs
   representing the various kinds of libraries you can add to your
   project. One of those tabs should list the "JSTL" library--my
   projects, for instance, use `jstl-1.2.jar`. If you don't see it in
   any of the libraries on your build path, you may need to add it
   manually by copying it to your project's external library folder and
   adding the JAR manually to your build path.

   See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F for more info.
2. After you add the library to your build path, you still have to
   make sure that the tags it contains are available to your specific
   JSP. In your example, you have:

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
   ```

   That allows you to use Spring's `form` tag library in your current JSP. I do not see a similar declaration for the `fmt` library, which I would expect to look something like:

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
   ```

   It's possible that you've got that in your `include.jsp` file; if so you should be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Palpatin Thank you for your kind and detailed answer. I add the jar you told me to do in 1st part. In second part, should I replace `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` with `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`or keep both?

Comment: And yes i have my include.jsp which is like this  `<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`

Comment: Point 1 is unnecessarily overcomplicated. Just drop JAR in project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. That's it. Eclipse will do the build path magic automatically.

Comment: @BalusC, true, but that only works if Eclipse is set up to autodiscover libraries in that directory, but it isn't always so.

Comment: @AbdulAziz You should keep both. If `include.jsp` already has it, then it's likely you won't need to add it separately. The fact that you're seeing an error message about the missing library implies that the webapp was attempting to load it and failing, so it's probably enough to simply add the JAR file to your project.

Comment: @Palpatim: Eclipse does that by default when the project is created as a "Dynamic web project". If the project isn't been created as such, you'll have many more problems than only the lack of autodiscovering.

Comment: @all Thank you all of your kind and generous help. my application is now working fine.